# Unable to upload content via google spreadsheet in Google Actions

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I am creating a Google Action's project using a Flash Card template. I am following the steps from [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/templates/flash-cards?authuser=0). But after updating the questions and answers, and other required field I am not able to upload contents from my sheet to google actions console like the documentation does in step 14.

After clicking on Upload in Step 13, I see a success message saying `check_circleYour content was uploaded successfully, 35 rows of content were detected` but when I click on Create App after that I see the following messages.

This is the error I see everytime I click on Upload

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug that has been resolved.

Comment: Still getting the issue Nick. English uploaded successfully but German translated upload failed.

Comment: Same error? The original bug was fixed, so it may be a new bug.