# I am trying to upload a Google sheet on a app on Google Assistance action console but it is giving error?

Tags: google-sheets, google-assistant-sdk

I am creating an app for google assistance using a template and I have uploaded an international language version but for now, it is giving me an error on uploading Hindi version.
It is uploading completely and all rows are detected but then on create app button it shows an error after some time like this

> Your sheet wasn't uploaded. Try again.
>         It looks like something went wrong in the upload process. We weren't 
>        able to determine the format of your Google Sheet. Learn more about 
>         the format here. Try it again.

I have checked everything, read every terms and condition, guidelines and everything is fine in my sheet but I don't know why it is showing this to me. Please help me.

Comment: Have you read this [Unable to upload content via google spreadsheet in Google Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56901220/1330560). It may have been resolved by now.